# Struggling with flask-socketio rooms

Tags: typeerror, flask-socketio

I have a project where I need to build a chat platform using flask-socketio. Everything works until I try to add rooms, I get the following error:

> application.py", line 92, in on_join
>       send({"msg", username + " has joined the " + room + " room."}, room=room) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType'
>   and 'str'

I'm not really sure where to look

```
@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    """User joins a room"""

    username = data["username"]
    room = data["room"]
    join_room(room)

    # Broadcast that new user has joined
    send({"msg", username + " has joined the " + room + " room."}, room=room)

     function joinRoom(room) {

            // Join room
            socket.emit('join', {'username': localStorage.getItem('displayname'), 'room': room});

            // Clear message area
             document.querySelector('#messages').innerHTML = '';

            // Autofocus on text box
            document.querySelector("#display-messages").focus();
        }
```

Should output "username has joined the 'roomname' room.", clear the message list as the channel changes, and allow you to speak in the new channel.

Comment: I'd guess that either `data['username']` or `data['room']` are being set to `None` by the client. I recommend you add a `console.log()` call above the `socket.emit()` in the client and print everything you are sending down to the server.